# Mail Session settings at Websphere Server

Tags: email, websphere

The mails are sent with default **From** address as wasadm@servername which I want to change. I tried using the property **mailFrom** at application.inf file,  changed the values at websphere console - **Resources >> Mail >> Mail Sessions >> Return e-mail address** but nothing worked out. 
Could you please let me know if you have some solution to replace the default from mail address to a custom value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the email-sending application code sets a "from" address in the message itself.

That said, I think it might work to set a Mail Session Custom property of `mail.from`. According to https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/overview-summary.html:

> **mail.from** The return email address of the current user, used
>   by the InternetAddress method getLocalAddress.

I know from experience that the *envelope sender address* can be set with Custom property `mail.smtp.from`. See https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

> **mail.smtp.from** Email address to use for SMTP MAIL command. This sets the envelope
>   return address. Defaults to msg.getFrom() or
>   InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(). NOTE: mail.smtp.user was previously
>   used for this.

Comment: it worked by setting the from address in code. thanks.